# Regular expression to remove repetitive characters

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this:

> i got sooome screeeewy inpuuuuut

I need to normalize it and beside other processing, I need to remove all repeated chars,
i.e. `soooome` becomes `some` and so on.

Grammar correctness does not matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need regex for this. Simply use `str.squeeze`:

```
str = 'i got sooome screeeewy inpuuuuut'
=> "i got sooome screeeewy inpuuuuut"

str.squeeze
=> "i got some screwy input"
```

**See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=regexp-to-remove-repetitive-chars.rb&run=true).**

Comment: Hopefully mangling words into other words is okay: `'good'.squeeze` as an example.

Comment: @tadman, here is an excerpt from OP: "Grammar correctness does not matter."

Answer (score 1):

slivu's answer is certainly the most succinct, but if you **have** to use a regex, you could use:

```
> 'i got sooome screeeewy inpuuuuut'.gsub(/(\w)\1+/, "\\1")
=> "i got some screwy input"
```